# Manipulate file data (byte array)

Tags: actionscript-3, file-upload, filereference

I'm totally new to ActionScript 3, though I'm a OOP coder.

I've seen with this snippet that I can easily change bytes one by one.

```
var j:int = myFile._fileRef.data.length;
while (j--)
{
    myfile._fileRef.data[j] += 128;
}
```

When I upload a file after applying a change to every byte, the results seems perfect.
But when I'm trying to directly assign a new bytearray (an encoded one) to the data member of _fileRef, the compiler reminds me that it is read only.

Is there an appropriate method to quickly modify the bytearray of the file before uploading it?

[EDIT]

Could it be in the method I use to assign a byte array?
I'm directly assigning an encoded array to the file:

```
myfile._fileRef.data = DESencodedArray;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are modifying a copy of the loaded `ByteArray`? Is there a reason why you are not working the loaded data directly, ie modify the `ByteArray` supplied via the `data` property?

Anyways, "replacing" the `ByteArray` contents can be done using [ByteArray::clear()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/ByteArray.html#clear%28%29) and  [ByteArray::writeBytes()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/ByteArray.html#writeBytes%28%29)

```
data.clear();
data.writeBytes(DESencodedArray);
```

Comment: Oh, I was still assigning the array with = instead of writing it. I'm trying 'write' on it.

Comment: I've noticed I always need to apply myArray.position = 0 on bytearrays I've written into. 2 hours passed before I realize my uploader (plupload) was reading a bytearray that has reached its end.